# Getting kotlin.TypeCastException when trying to use parcelable on an ArrayList variable which contains null fields

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, parcelable

I literally started yesterday with using Kotlin, so I am still having a hard time understanding the underlying principles. I want to send an object via intent to another activity and implemented parcelable on the object. The object contains some MutableLists in the form of:

```
var favoritePlaces: MutableList<String?>? = null
```

I used this method constructor to parcelize it:

```
constructor(`in`: Parcel) {
  `in`.readList(favoritePlaces, String::class.java.classLoader)
}
```

This is the error I get  in Android Studio since a type mismatch exists:

[image: Android Studio error]

I tried to go with the suggestion of Android Studio leaving me with this here in the constructor:

```
constructor(`in`: Parcel) {
   `in`.readList(favoritePlaces as List<*>, String::class.java.classLoader)
 }
```

And in the writeToParcel method:

```
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeList(favoritePlaces as List<*>?)
}
```

But when I try to use this, then I get the following error message when starting the Activity:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test.app.Activity}:
>   kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
>   kotlin.collections.List<*>

I do understand that the type kotlin.collections.List<*> is a non-null type and since I have some null fields in my arrays, it makes sense that this error occurs. My question is now, how can I parcelize String Arrays in Kotlin with non-empty as well as empty fields???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readList` expects a non-null argument list to which it will add elements, so you need to initialize it before calling `readList`:

```
favoritePlaces = mutableListOf<String?>()
`in`.readList(favoritePlaces as List<*>, String::class.java.classLoader)
```

Or better,

```
favoritePlaces = `in`.createStringArrayList()
```

But in Kotlin there's basically no reason to do this manually; use [`@Parcelize`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable-implementations-generator) instead if possible (you'll need to move properties to the primary constructor instead of class body).

Comment: Thanks for this, I was thinking of using @Parcelize and had a look at it, it seems great to use an autogenerator to parcelize it, saves some boilerplate!